# ScrollView padding

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-scrollview

I'm trying to use ScrollView with an ImageView in it.
My xml code for it is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tapjoy_dialog_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/untitled" />

</ScrollView>
```

Strangely, when I run it, the image shows up with a very-wide-padding on the top and bottom of it. To understand what I mean please take a look at the screenshot I attached.

[image: ScrollView snapshot]

How can I solve this?

More strangely:

1. When I remove the ScrollView, and leave the ImageView only, it doesn't pad and work nicely.
2. When I remove the ImageView and place a big textView instead it also doesn't pad and work nicely.

So, I think the problem is somewhat related to the combination of the ScrollView and the ImageView...

The image I try to put in the ImageView is this:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean? just wrap the ImageView with a RelativeLayout?
If so, I tried it now, and it donsn't work...

Comment: remove the   android:fillViewport="true" or just set it to false and run it.

Comment: Actually, in the beginning I tried it without the fillViewport, I added it to try manipulate the ScrollView to work properly...
It doesn't work...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to your `ImageView`.

Comment: Thank you, after hours I spent on this thing, your one-line answer did the trick... :)

Answer (score 0):

//add one parent layout for your scroll view

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    android:layout_gravity="right" >
<LinearLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tapjoy_dialog_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/untitled" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: @user1028741 change   android:fillViewport="false"

Comment: I tried removing the fillViewort - it doesn't change anything - still the same thing...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you mean?
The image of the result ScrollView? I attached it in the question.
Can you explain what image you're reffering to?

Comment: I want the  android:src="@drawable/untitled so that I will try here.